# Инициализация const unsigned char[] при объявлении

Tags: c++

Как инициализировать массив `const unsigned char[]` при объявлении?

Пишу так:

```
// RGB colors
const unsigned char red[]   = { 255,0,0 },
                    green[] = { 0,255,0 },
                    blue[]  = { 0,0,255 },
                    black[] = { 0, 0 ,0 },
                    white[] = { 255,255,255 };
const unsigned char my_color[] = red; // <- error
```

Получаю ошибку:

> [Error] initializer fails to determine size of 'background_color'

Добавляю явный размер:

```
const unsigned char background_color[3] = red;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> [Error] array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Т.е. можно только через `{}`? Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В даном случаи вы присваиваете массиву my_color указатель red , это ошибка

```
const unsigned char my_color[] = red;
```

Правильно присваивать вот так

```
const unsigned char * my_color = red;
```

или так

```
 const unsigned char * my_color[] = {red,green,blue,black,white};
```

Но если вы хотите скопировать массив red в массив my_color то только прямое копирование

```
my_color[0] = red[0];
my_color[1] = red[1];
my_color[2] = red[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Основное затруднение у Вас в том, что операция присваивания для массивов не определена, а для инициализации переменной при ее объявлении нужны фигурные скобки.

Однако, если вспомнить о препроцессоре, то Ваши инициализации можно записать вот так:

```
#define COLOR(r,g,b) { r, g, b }
#define RED          COLOR(255, 0, 0)
#define GREEN        COLOR(0, 255, 0)
#define BLUE         COLOR(0, 0, 255)
#define BLACK        COLOR(0, 0, 0)
#define WHITE        COLOR(255, 255, 255)

const unsigned char red[]   = RED,
  green[] = GREEN,
  blue[]  = BLUE,
  black[] = BLACK,
  white[] = WHITE;

const unsigned char my_color[] = RED; // <- No error

int main()
{
   // ...
}
```

Если же Вы хотите использовать присваивания цветов в исполняемой части программы, то можно пойти чуть дальше и написать, например, так
(поскольку структуры присваивать можно)

```
// макросы для цветов остались прежними
struct color {
  unsigned char color[3];
};

const color red = RED,
  green = GREEN,
  blue = BLUE,
  black = BLACK,
  white = WHITE,
  my_color = RED;


int main()
{
  // теперь цветами можно манипулировать таким образом
  color x, y = BLACK, z;

  x = (color)WHITE;
  y = (color)COLOR(1,2,3);
  z = my_color;
  z.color[1] = 200;
}
```

Comment: Зачем макросы структурам?

Comment: @Qwertiy, для красоты... .